# Getting all emails sent to a user via REST Api

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'd like to build a page outside of marketing cloud that shows all the emails a specific customer has recieved. Is this something I could get over the API. Campaign name, date send and (if applicable) date opened?

I had a rummage through the docs and nothing jumped out at me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SOAP API can provide that information.  It isn't returned in a single call, it is split out by the event type.  The SentEvent can be used to find all of the instances that someone was sent an email, then the OpenEvent can be used to see if they opened.

Example for retrieving SendEvent:
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieve_sentevent_details_for_job/